# Azure Synapse Studio- unable to create SQL Pool

Tags: azure-synapse

Ref: [What is Azure Synapse Analytics (workspaces preview)?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/overview-what-is)

While creating an `Azure Synapse Workspace` (in step 1 of [this Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-create-workspace)), when I try to [create SQL Pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-create-workspace#create-a-sql-pool), I get the `New` button option disabled as shown below. I am the owner and the contributor on the Azure account, so I am not sure why the `New` button is disabled. Maybe, someone with `Azure Synapse` knowledge can help.

[image]

**UPDATE**:

I am the `Global Administrator` who owns the Azure Subscription that means I owns everything on that subscription and hence have full control on all the resources. Following is the screenshot of my `Azure AD`. My subscription is `Visual Studio Enterprise – MPN`. Is there something else I need to have?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't have proper permissions to create SQL pools known as SQL Admin.

[image]

Make sure you have proper permissions to create SQL Pools.

[image]

To secure a Synapse workspace (preview), you'll follow a pattern of configuring the following items:

- Azure roles (such as the built-in ones like Owner, Contributor, etc.)
- Synapse roles – these roles are unique to Synapse and aren't based on
  Azure roles. There are three of these roles:
  => Synapse workspace admin
  => Synapse SQL admin
  => Apache Spark for Azure Synapse Analytics admin
- Access control for data in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 2 (ADLSGEN2).
- Access control for Synapse SQL and Spark databases

**Reference:** [Secure your Synapse workspace (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-set-up-access-control#step-5-configure-admin-access-for-sql-pools)

Comment: I am the global administrator. I have just added an **UPDATE** section. Please let me know if I am still missing something.